# Stop Ms SQL server from formatting view queries in Design

Tags: sql-server, view

After making a beautiful clear sql query, when you make a new view with that code in the design screen, sql server makes the code ugly and hard to read.

But now trying to use a linked server which contains a "\", I originally had [ ] around the name, but after putting this in to a new view, sql server uglifies it and removes the [ ] therefore telling me the \ is incorrect syntax.

I can't find a way to stop sql server management studio from crapping all over my query in a view design window.

Comment: The easiest solution is to stop using the design window. You don't need, especially since it sounds like you know what the sql needs to be. Just write your view and forget that horrific design window exists.

Comment: Yeah thats what I've been doing, the problem now is I need the [ ] brackets to use a slash in an object name, the designer removes them, so I can not proceed.

Comment: Well, either stop putting slashes in object names (preferred) and/or stop using the designer. To be honest all I have ever seen from the designer is using [around] [everything].

Answer (score 0):

I use APEX SQL Refactor to create code in the format that I like. You can set your profile settings. It's a one time investment that's definately rewarding.

Not only for your situation (which I am unfamiliair with by the way). But also when working with code from external sources or co-workers.